# Liquibase checksum value prefix

Tags: liquibase

I want to create a changeset with a validChecksum field, so I looked into the DATABASECHANGELOG table and noticed the entries have a prefix.

E.g.: 1:7ad9f8d1a1b4abc71f2eab8131d456b

How much of that should be used as input? The actual checksum is only what follows after the colon, but will it still work without the prefix 1: ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1:` prefix is the version of the checksum algorithm that was used to calculate the checksum. Over the life of the Liquibase project, that algorithm has changed a few times, and the version is used internally to know if a checksum needs to be 'updated' to a newer version in the case where you have a database that has been managed by Liquibase with checksum algorithm version X and then start using Liquibase with checksum algorithm version X+1.

That's a lot of information you didn't ask for :-)

To answer the question - when putting a `<validCheckSum>` attribute on a changeset, you can  use either the one with the version prefix or without it. The comparison is done only on the value, not on the prefix.

Comment: Information I don't ask for is the best kind of information. Thank you for the context!